# Component is not updating on Button Click, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a parent component 'Menu' and a child component 'DishDetails'. The child component returns a Card on Button Click. It works for the first time when i click on the button. The component is not updated while i again click on  button. The Component should update after clicking on the Button.

**Parent Component**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import DishDetails from './DishDetails'
import { Card,CardImg,CardImgOverlay,CardTitle,CardBody,CardText} from 'reactstrap'


class Menu extends Component{
//The class base component must have a constructor with super statment
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        dishSelection:null
    }
}

//Method when the user click on the image
onDish(dish){
    this.setState({dishSelection:dish})
}

renderDish(dish){
    if(dish!=null){
        return(
            <DishDetails dish = {dish}></DishDetails>
        )
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}

//The component should implement the render method
render(){
    //Declare a variable for the defining the list 
    const media = this.props.dishes.map((dish)=>{
        return(
            <div className='col-12 col-md-5 m-2'>
                <Card onClick={()=>this.onDish(dish)} key={dish.id}>
                    <CardImg  src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div> 
        )
    })

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                {media}
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className = 'col-12'>
                    {this.renderDish(this.state.dishSelection)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       )
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import {Card,CardImg,CardImgOverlay,CardTitle} from 'reactstrap'

class DishDetails extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dish : this.props.dish
    }
}

render(){
    //const dish = this.props.dish;
    console.log(this.state.dish.name)
    return(
        <div>
            <div className = 'col-12 col-md-5'>
                <Card key={this.state.dish.id}>
                    <CardImg  src={this.state.dish.image} alt={this.state.dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <CardTitle>{this.state.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div> 
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default DishDetails;
```

Answer (score 2):

Constructor fires for the first time only. Don't make copy of props in state if you don't need to change the value inside child component. Change this.state.dish to this.props.dish in child component.

```
class DishDetails extends Component{

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className = 'col-12 col-md-5'>
                <Card key={this.props.dish.id}>
                    <CardImg  src={this.props.dish.image} alt={this.state.dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <CardTitle>{this.props.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div> 
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default DishDetails;
```

Or if you still want to update the state on any change in parent component then you should have a look at this link :-

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @HAMMADALI if my answer helped you then please upvote my answer. Thank you

Comment: i really apologies for this. My reputation is less than 15 so i can't upvote your answer.

Comment: @HAMMADALI no issues. Thank you for your reply. 

Comment: My reputation is increased. I have given you upvote :)